# What to set in userPrefs to open devtools at the bottom in puppeteer-extra?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I looked https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1797, and tried below setting, but devtools was still opened on right side.

Does anyone know what to set in userPrefs to open devtools at the bottom in puppeteer-extra?

```
            puppeteer.use(require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences')({
            userPrefs: {
                devtools: {
                    currentDockState: "bottom"
                }
            }
        }))
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
puppeteer.use(require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences')({
            userPrefs: {
                devtools: {
                    currentDockState: '"bottom"'
                }
            }
        }))
```